# How do I use 'include' to apply rules to a capture when writing a Sublime Text syntax definition?

Tags: regex, syntax-highlighting, sublimetext3

I'm trying to write a syntax definition for Gradle in Sublime Text 3. Many pieces of a Gradle build file are really just Groovy and so I'm trying to take advantage of the current Groovy highlighting support by using `include`. Thus far this is working fairly well, by I'm stuck on how to apply it to a particular piece.

Here is the Gradle snippet I am trying to highlight:

```
task copyTask (group: 'Install NGA - deploy', type: Copy, dependsOn: 'whoCares') {
   from 'resources'
   into 'target'
   include('**/*.txt')
}
```

And this is the syntax I'm using to match that snippet:

```
- name: copy.task.source.gradle
  begin: '\s*(task)\s+(\w+)\s*\((.*type: Copy.*)\)\s*{'
  comment: 'Copy task definition'
  beginCaptures:
    '1': {name: keyword.task.source.gradle}
    '2': {name: entity.name.function}
    '3': {name: source.groovy}
  end: '}'
  contentName: copy.body.source.gradle
  patterns:
    - include: source.groovy
```

Most of this appears to work as intended. (Always hard to know with RegEx.) My problem is that the third capture. I want to apply *all* the rules contained in 'source.groovy' to the text between the parentheses and what I have above is not getting the job done.

To clarify: the text is "captured" and tagged as source.groovy, but that's not actually quite what I want. I don't want it simply tagged as source.groovy, I want the rules from source.groovy to be used when evaluating the text. The last line of my example successfully does this to the "content" section (text in between the braces) but simply putting include does not work.

```
'3': {include: source.groovy} # This gets an error.
```

If there is a syntax to apply include directly to a capture I can't find it, and I can't figure out another technique. Maybe something that has nested `begin` and `end` tags?

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding this correctly you would like the third capture group `source.groovy` to match the `group: 'Install NGA - deploy', type: Copy, dependsOn: 'whoCares'` part of your example.

In that case you would just need to alter you expression to capture more of the string like so:

```
begin: '\s*(task)\s+(\w+)\s*\((.*type: Copy.*?)\)\s*{'
```

Comment: You did find a hole in my RegEx, but even the part that was successfully captured and was successfully tagged as source.groovy did not highlight as groovy code. Thanks for the catch! I will try to make the question clearer.